# RewriteCond and Rewrite Rule to Find a Query String and Redirect to a Fixed Web Page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to find the correct code to redirect a URL with query parameters to a specific URL with no parameters.  For example, I have the following URL:

```
https://www.sample.org/book-order-success?reading-choice=Read%20on%20Website&reading-choice-second=
```

I would like to redirect this page:

```
https://www.sample.org/no-more-delay-on-website
```

Here is the code that I have written, but I get a 500 internal server error when I try to implement it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)reading-choice=Read(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.sample.org/no-more-delay-on-website [QSD,R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I am trying to do a response form with conditional results using Contact Form 7 from a WordPress site.  There are about five conditions that produce a link like the first example.  I would like to provide a specific response to the user based on their choice of conditions within the form.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
MPurvis

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually create pages in WordPress for your redirects?

Can you open them with URL of them without any errors?

I mean pages like **'book-order-success'** and **'no-more-delay-on-website'**. They must be created or you just want redirecting to external URL.

Why don't do that with some PHP code instead of htaccess?
In WordPress and PHP you can check your query parameters from your URL which actually are GET requests. It's easier.

```
function check_query_parameters() {
// is_page() - which page has query parameters you can type page id, slug etc.
  if(is_page('book-order-success')){
    $query_paremeter = $_GET['reading-choice'];
    if (isset($query_paremeter) && $query_paremeter == 'Read On Website') {

     // redirect to a specific URL
     header("Location: https://www.sample.org/no-more-delay-on-website");
     die();

    }
}

add_action( 'wp', 'check_query_parameters' );
```

You can try it by coping it into **functions.php** in your current WordPress Theme.

Description of **functions.php**: *"The functions file behaves like a WordPress Plugin, adding features and functionality to a WordPress site through PHP code. You can use it to call native PHP functions, WordPress functions, or to define your own functions."*

### Documentation:

**GET requests ($_GET):** http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

**is_page():** https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/

**functions.php:** https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained

Comment: I'll give the .php a shot.  I know enough about php to get myself in trouble, but if I have something like this to work with, it helps tremendously.  And yes, I do have the pages set up already and they work fine on my internal website. Will this work for separate variations of the same URL parameters.  I have five different response pages I want to open up depending on the parameter settings? Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can redirect your URL depending on your parameters by adding next if statement like: `if (isset($query_paremeter) && $query_paremeter == 'Read On Website') {

     // redirect to a specific URL
     header("Location: https://www.sample.org/no-more-delay-on-website");
     die();

    }`

Answer (score 0):

After trying php coding as well as other options a shot without success, I found a paid plugin that works with Contact Form 7.  The one that worked for me was https://codecanyon.net/item/contact-form-7-redirects-thank-you-and-failed-page/20211250